# How many repeated steps in a Fibonacci recursive function

Tags: recursion, fibonacci-numbers, recursive-algorithms

how can i calculate how many repeated calls occur in a fib recursive function.

> fib(n):
>
> if n = 0 : ret 0
>
> if n = 1 : ret 1
>
> ret fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)

ex) if n = 5 how many times fib(3), fib(2), fib(1) are repeated in **total** ? We know that fib(5) and fib(4) are only called once.

Comment: Any thoughts?  Can you, say, solve the example case you set?

Comment: Just do the first few cases by hand. You should be able to spot the almost comically apt pattern pretty quickly.

Comment: @lulu when i draw out the recursive tree it seems only the root node and one of its child node is not repeated but  rest are repeated. Now the issue im having is that the last level of the tree is not always full so how can i factor that into my calculation?

Comment: Question has surely been asked & answered on this site many times before. See, for example, the questions listed under "Related".

Comment: See here: https://zhu45.org/posts/2017/Jan/22/num-of-function-calls-in-recursive-fibonacci-routine/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here for analysis that shows that the number of function calls to compute $F(n)$ is $2F(n)-1$: https://zhu45.org/posts/2017/Jan/22/num-of-function-calls-in-recursive-fibonacci-routine/

Now, since $F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)$ with $F(0)=F(1)=1$ is a homogeneous second-order linear recurrence with constant coefficients, it has a solution of the form
$$
F(n) = c_1 r_1^n + c_2r_2^n
$$
where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants and $r_1, r_2$ are the roots of the characteristic polynomial $x^2 - x -1 $. Solving, we find that $r_1 = \frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)$, $r_2= \frac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)$, and from the initial conditions we have
\begin{align}
1 &= F(0) = c_1\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)\right)^0 + c_2\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)\right)^0 = c_1+c_2\\
1 &= F(1) = c_1\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)\right)^1 + c_2\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)\right)^1\\
&\implies c_2 = 1-c_1\\
&\quad\implies c_1 = \frac{1}{10} \left(5-\sqrt{5}\right),\quad c_2 = \frac{1}{10} \left(\sqrt{5}+5\right).
\end{align}
Hence the number of function calls to compute $F(n)$ is
$$
\frac{1}{50}\left( \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)\right)^n +\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)\right)^n \right) -1.
$$

(Note that there are vastly more efficient algorithms for computing the Fibonacci numbers!)

Comment: thanks for putting time into this! but this doesnt tell me how many of these calls are repeated. But i am gonna assume it is your answer - 2.